# cannot find symbol“_mm256_max_epu8” when I want to use AVX2 instruction in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, avx2

**Environment:** Win10, Intel Core i7 5500U CPU, Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

[image: enter image description]

[image]

Now I want to use "_mm256_max_epu8" Intel SIMD instruction which is in AVX2,but the Visual Studio 2010 tells me that:

1>..\svCore\svGrayMorph.cpp(838): error C3861: “_mm256_max_epu8”: 找不到标识符

I have found that AVX2 instructions should be declared in file:

...\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\immintrin.h

However, the file only have AVX instructions, the "_mm256_max_epu8" and other instructions are not in that file.

While the immintrin.h file of Visual Studio 2013 include the AVX2 instruction.

Do SomeOne Know What I can Do to compile this code in Visual Studio 2010 ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Pretty sure AVX2 was first supported in VS2013.

Comment: Did you add the `/arch:AVX` option to your project?

Comment: @paddy already have a try, did not work.

Comment: @CoryNelson  so no solution in VS2010?

Comment: `Visual Studio 2010` support: [/arch:[SSE|SSE2|AVX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t5yh4fd(v=vs.100).aspx). and avx2 is supported only from [Visual Studio 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t5yh4fd(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: @H.DJEMAI Thanks， Can you tell me where can I find different VS IDE support what instruction?

Comment: I was looking for that without luck, I'm looking to use [this program](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-detect-new-instruction-support-in-the-4th-generation-intel-core-processor-family):  for my fourth gen, don't know if its applicable for 5gen intel

Comment: @jianqiao yang: The links you requested are in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As it was written earlier Visual Studio 2010 doesn't support AVX2 and you have to use Visual Studio 2013.

But if you want to use universal code which will be compilable in both versions of Visual Studio you have to use conditional compilation with using of macros.

There is an example:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER >= 1700 //Visual Studio 2013
#define AVX2_ENABLE
#endif

#ifdef AVX2_ENABLE
void func()
{
     //code with AVX2
}
#else
void func()
{
     //code without AVX2
}
#endif
```

[Here](https://github.com/ermig1979/Simd) you can find more examples how to use different SIMD extensions in the one project.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion ~~

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the symbol `_mm256_max_epu8` can be used with [Visual Studio 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh977023(v=vs.120).aspx) or [Visual Studio 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh977023(v=vs.110).aspx) as found in those two Intrinsics Lists.

And of course it works as well with [VS2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh977023(v=vs.140).aspx)

> But does not exist in [visual studio 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5704bbxw(v=vs.100).aspx)
>
> Visual Studio 2010 support: [/arch:SSE|SSE2|AVX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t5yh4fd(v=vs.100).aspx),
>
> And Visual Studio 2013 support: [/arch:IA32|SSE|SSE2|AVX|AVX2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t5yh4fd(v=vs.120).aspx)